# Is it possible to reference another system property in system property while providing referencing property as jvm option?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Setting it programmatically is possible:

```
System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/tmpdir");
```

Is there any way to set system property, which references another system property as jvm option? (with either implicitly or explicitly set referenced property)

I tried:

- -Djava.io.tmpdir=$user.home/tmpdir
- -Djava.io.tmpdir=${user.home}/tmpdir
- -Djava.io.tmpdir=-Duser.home/tmpdir
- -Dtest.ref=/home/wort -Djava.io.tmpdir=-Dtest.ref/test
- -Dtest.ref=/home/wort -Djava.io.tmpdir=$test.ref/test

Comment: not without implementing something like https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java | doing as your code does

Comment: doing  "that"..you can have "better support" from "env (variables) replacement/substitution"

Comment: Well, `-Djava.io.tmpdir=${HOME}/tmpdir` might work on the command line as the shell will substitute the variable before starting the program.

Comment: @Holger, right, but it is not fully portable and expands environment variables of the operating system, not Java system properties.

Comment: @aled this example is system specific anyway.

Comment: @aled Yes, I did not want to bring environment variables to my case and also stay platform independent.